# I need assistance with building GIMP to run under AWS EC2 instance and Lambda

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, gimp

TLDR; I need to build an instance of the Gimp application that runs under AWS in a Lambda and on an EC2 linux.

I'm building a micro service that uses AWS API Gateway with python Lambdas. I have the deployment package built that will allow the use of Django ORM and MySQL (AWS RDS). I need to get Gimp into the deployment package.

In order to get it into the deployment package I need to build (compile/install/whatever) the app.

I've tried doing an install with an RPM from rpmfind but it has dependencies that I can't seem to find within the AWS repos.

Oh, and `sudo yum install gimp` doesn't work either on the EC2 instance

I'm open to suggestions.

Oh, and my reason for using Gimp, I need to create layered PSDs. I know of only two tools that can do that: Photoshop and Gimp. I'll be using the Python features of Gimp to build the PSD. I did my testing / research under Windows and it worked. My restrictions (out of my hands) are AWS, API Gateway and Lambdas.

Thanks

Comment: ImageMagick can't do this? (i.e. you have tried, failed, and can tell us the command you've tried)

Comment: Ok, I didnt know about imagemagick.  I pulled it down onto the EC2 without any problems and it runs.  I need help with getting the parameters correct,  is there a forum for help on it somewhere?

Comment: The parameters are described in great detail, for example on the ImageMagick website. It is unlikely that you have read them yet, given you just discovered this application. I suggest you do this before asking questions anywhere, this will benefit everyone involved.